# How to show loader image until controller method completes in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have an `Index` page like below and on button click I have some code to save data into database and then it goes on details page.

But I the code should go to the details page only after completing the database save operation; I want to show a loader image until then; how can I do this?

Currently I'm using begin post to post method and bind all model not using any ajax call. How can I show loader image and render before process complete to details page?

Index.cshtml

```
@model Dev.Models.DeviceReg
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddAsync", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h4 id="aa">Name</h4>
                    <label>Select</label>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Name, (SelectList)ViewBag.Name, "---Select Name---")
                            </td>                           
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h4 id="aa">Model</h4>
                    <label>Select</label>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Type, (SelectList)ViewBag.TypeName, "---Select Type---")
                            </td>                          
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>              
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer" align="left">
            <button type="submit" id="save" class="btn btn-success">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span> save 
            </button>
        </div>       
    </div>
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
public async Task<ActionResult> AddAsync(DeviceReg deviceRegistration)
{        

        foreach (var deviceId in collection)
        {
                // save device information into database
                Models.Device newDevice = new Models.Device()
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    DeviceTypeId = deviceRegistration.DeviceType,
                    PlatformId = deviceRegistration.PlatformType,
                    DeviceId = deviceId,
                };

                _repository.InsertDevice(newDevice);
                _repository.Save();
        }
    return View("Details", deviceRegistration);
}
```

Details.cshml

```
@model Dev.Models.DeviceReg

<body style="background-color:black">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">

        <div class="panel-heading" align="center">
            <h2 class="panel-title">Details</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h3><label>Current Data</label></h3>
                    <br />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h4 id="aa">Name</h4>
                    <label>@Model.Name</label>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h4 id="aa">Type</h4>
                    <label>@Model.TypeName</label>

                </div>
            </div>

            <hr />
            <br />
            <label>Your process is running.</label>
            <br />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h3><label>Status</label></h3>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div style="clear: both">
                        <h2 style="float: left">10</h2>
                        <h6 style="float: right">Active Number</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>


    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Since you are using `async Task<ActionResult> AddAsync` async controller action it will redirect immediately try using non-async controller action like `public ActionResult Add(DeviceReg deviceRegistration)`

Comment: I want to go to details page immediately but want to show loader till save complete how to achieve this ? any link ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if you need to show loader while post form is submitting, you can use javascript functions to show it, like

```
            @using (Html.BeginForm("AddAsync", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "showLoader(this);" }))
            {
                  ...
            }
```

plus JS

```
    <script>
        var showLoader = function(form){
            $("<div />").css({
                'position' : 'fixed',
                'left' : 0,
                'right' : 0,
                'bottom' : 0,
                'top' : 0,
                'background' : '#0020ff36',
                'z-index' : '99',
                'text-align' : 'center'
            }).appendTo($("body"))
              .append(
                $("<img />").attr("src", "https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/disp/35771931234507.564a1d2403b3a.gif")
            );
        }
    </script>
```

or by jquery event, like

```
    <script>
        $("form").submit(function(){
            //show loader
        });
    </script>
```

example of this code https://dotnetfiddle.net/gfEVSE

**But**, regarding to your clarification of the issue in comments, it's impossible to show Details page with progress of saving without Javascript or another additional requests.

Example without ajax but with aditional requests every N seconds

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddAsync(SampleViewModel deviceRegistration)
    {   
        Task.Run(()=>
        {
            //Saving to DB
        });
        return RedirectToAction("Details", id = deviceRegistration.id);
    }
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        var isObjectExistInDb = checkIfExistInDb(id);
        if (!isObjectExistInDb){
            return View("ShowLoader", id);
        }

        return View(object);
    }
```

where in ShowLoader.cshtml you need to reload page every N seconds.

With ajax it will be more clear, pretty code. Please, let me know, if you need example with ajax :)

Comment: ok thank you please share an example with ajax call thanks in advance :)

Comment: how to bind this near submit button?
`<style>.loader {  border: 6px solid #f3f3f3;  border-radius: 50%;  border-top: 6px solid #3498db;  width: 20px;  height: 20px;  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;}/* Safari */@-webkit-keyframes spin {  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }}spin {  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}</style></head><body><div class="loader"></div></body>`

Comment: Nice solution ! I just had yo add some margin-top to the img itself to position it horizontally.